# Can I be sure that Android application finished running by checking isFinish() in the main Activity's onPause()?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have to clear some application data after my application is finished running.As far as I know `onDestroy()` may not be called. So I decided to check if `isFinishing() == true` in `onPause()` of the root activity to see whether this activity and other ones of my app are in the process of finishing. But I doubt if this activity:

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.test.AuthorizationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

will be a root activity? And is this a correct way in general?

Comment: You can call  FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  to make sure that all the activities will finish on your onPause()...Have you tried that..?

Comment: I think you need android:finishOnTaskLaunch in your activity manifest. You can read more at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to rethink your design because it seems that it `isFinishing` is true only when `finish` is called on the activity and does not account for cases where the activity is destroyed because of low memory.

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29):

> This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. **You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.**

For what you are suggesting you could possibly store the application's state data in `static` variables, which will be cleared when your application process ends (when the last activity/ service is finished).

Answer (score 0):

Where did you read that `onDestroy` may not be called? `onDestroy` is called when the application is finished, according to the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29).

Is there any chance that you are mixing up going into background versus being destroyed?

Applications have different lifetimes: the entire, visible and foreground lifetimes. Different callbacks are called for those state changes, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle).

Comment: Actually, `onDestroy` is not guaranteed to be called. That is documented in the documentation you linked to. "There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it ..."

Comment: @Dallas: I may be going blind over here. Can you please quote the piece that says `onDestroy` is not guaranteed to be called when an application is being removed from memory (I understand it's not called when it's simply moved to foreground)? I read all references to `onDestroy` again in the lifecycle and didn't find anything qualifying when it is (or is not) called.

Comment: Sorry for the moment of stupidity. I see your quote in the first comment. In that case I wonder if there is any need to clean up application data nicely anyway, since Android is yanking it out.

Comment: @Dallas is right: the lifecycle is not guaranteed when your process is killed by the LowMemoryKiller. You will not get an onDestroy() call at that point. So essentially, think of Activity.onDestroy() as an opportunity to clean up your app's in-memory state -- not any external stuff. This is [documented in the API for onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy() is called when activity is destroyed. so if we want to check weather application is closed or not then we have to implement the generic service that can inform us the status of application.